# increase thread count in Spring reactor AsyncTaskExecutor

Tags: spring, reactor, project-reactor

How do I increase the thread count while using thread pool
my code is as follows,

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableReactor
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {
    @Autowired
    private Reactor reactor

    @Bean
    Reactor createReactor(Environment env) {
    return Reactors.reactor()
            .env(env)
            .dispatcher(Environment.THREAD_POOL)
            .get();
    }
```

Adding the following code did not increase the thread count, which is fixed by default to the number of cores on the machine.

```
@Bean
public AsyncTaskExecutor workQueueAsyncTaskExecutor(Environment env) {
    return new WorkQueueAsyncTaskExecutor(env)
        .setName("workQueueExecutor")
        .setBacklog(2048)
        .setThreads(20)
        .setWaitStrategy(new YieldingWaitStrategy());
}
```

How do I set the thread count for my reactor variable?

If I remove the `createReactor` bean, the reactor works fine, it's just that the default is `RingBuffer` single thread. With that bean and the specification of `THREAD_POOL`, threads equal to the number of cores on the machine are launched.
I am just trying to see how I can increase that count manually...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was answered by @jbrisbin on gitter, https://gitter.im/reactor/reactor?at=5548f40f52bceea22c3814e0

just for convenience, the answer is to create a bean for the dispatcher and refer to it from the reactor creation bean

```
@Bean
Reactor createReactor(Environment env) {
    Reactor r = Reactors.reactor().env(env).dispatcher(createDispatcher()).get();
    return r;
}

@Bean
Dispatcher createDispatcher() {
    Dispatcher d = new WorkQueueDispatcher("multThreadedQueueDispatcher", 20, 2048, null);
    return d;
}
```